# Passing data from a UIPickerView to a UIViewController in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently trying to build a simple app in Swift 5 that has a main `UIViewController`:

```
class TheList: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    (...)
}
```

The `UIViewController` has an Extension that utilises the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.

```
extension TheList: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

(...)

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "titleViewCell")!
            return cell

(...)

}
```

It populates the table with certain dynamic `UITableViewCells`, that are their own, separate classes. Here's an example of one:

```
class AmtTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet var hoursPickerView: UIPickerView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        populate()
        hoursPickerView.delegate = self
        hoursPickerView.dataSource = self
    }

(...)
}

extension AmtTableViewCell: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return String(pickerData[row])
    }


}
```

As you can see, that `UITableViewCell` has an outlet of a `UIPickerView`. I would like to somehow pass the data from this class's `UIPickerView` to my `UIViewController`, so that I can parse it further there. I've tried to create a method to do so and then call it in my View Controller, but from I understood I had to instantiate it first, which kills the point, as I would like to get the value from the instance the user sees on their screen.

I have also tried to create an outlet for the Picker in my View Controller and then set up its Delegate and Data Source as the `AmtTableViewCell` class instead of `self` but I've learned I can't put that `UIPickerView` in my `UIViewController`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you hav e two options closures and delegates.

Comment: how do you handle the picker selection is not shown. have you set a custom buttom or just the picker delegate method didSelectItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using closures:

```
class AmtTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet var hoursPickerView: UIPickerView!
    var selectedValueInPicker: ((String) -> Void)?
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        populate()
        hoursPickerView.delegate = self
        hoursPickerView.dataSource = self
    }

(...)
}
extension AmtTableViewCell: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return String(pickerData[row])
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
        selectedValueInPicker?(String(pickerData[row]))
    }

}

extension TheList: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

(...)

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "titleViewCell") as? AmtTableViewCell
            cell.selectedValueInPicker = { val in
               //Do what is needed with the Stirng val that is comming from the cell passes in closure
            }
            return cell ?? AmtTableViewCell()

(...)

}
```

Using Protocol delegate

```
protocol PickerSelectedValue{
    func didSelectValueInPicker(value: String)
}

class AmtTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet var hoursPickerView: UIPickerView!
    var delegate: PickerSelectedValue?
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        populate()
        hoursPickerView.delegate = self
        hoursPickerView.dataSource = self
    }

(...)
}
extension AmtTableViewCell: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return String(pickerData[row])
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
        delegate?.didSelectValueInPicker(String(pickerData[row]))
    }

}

extension TheList: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,pickerSelectedValue{

(...)

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "titleViewCell") as? AmtTableViewCell
            cell?.delegate = self
            return cell ?? AmtTableViewCell()

(...)
    func didSelectValueInPicker(value: String){
        print("the selected value in picker was",value)
    }

}
```

the delegate protocol is little big long in code, but maybe easier to understand is not confortable with closures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I still couldn't get either way to work. The code is semantically correct and it does compile, however the data doesn't seem to get passed or I'm doing something wrong. Using the delegate approach, in TheList class I've created a variable 'a', then in didSelectValueInPicker function I've put 'a = value' and created a Button action where it should print 'a', and I would expect it to do so, but it doesn't.

Comment: pues without look you code that is wrong, update it to show your changes to help you

Comment: Turns out it was my fault with a misconfigured button! I can confirm that the delegate method works well now, thank you for help.